# Does this paragraph sound native?

Tags: word-choice

> The bill of July **was issued** on August 2nd and **the amount of your bill** is $113 and you have a grace period till August 23rd so please **make sure to pay it** before that date to prevent any barring on your line and to keep your line working.

1. Should I say (was issued) or (issued)?
2. Should I say (the amount of your bill) or (it'll be)?
3. Should I say (make sure to pay) or (make sure that you pay)?
4. Do I need the pronoun (it) after (pay)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd appreciate a little more context behind this question because superficially it sounds like you are writing the content behind a phishing email.

Giving you the benefit of the doubt though...

First of all, it's not a paragraph - it's a single sentence that uses "and" too many times.

Breaking it down & rewording it -

> *The bill of July was issued on August 2nd and the amount of your bill is $113*

I would replace with

> "Your bill for July was issued on August 2nd for a total amount of $113".

The bill of July implies there is only a single bill issued in July, and if this is some form of telecoms delayed payment charge, there would be a LOT more bills issued.

> *and you have a grace period till August 23rd so please make sure to pay it before that date to prevent any barring on your line and to keep your line working.*

Remove the first and, starting a new sentence. Till is antiquated,albeit legitimate, with "until" usually preferred on formal documentation.

> "You have a grace period until August 23rd to settle your account. Failure to do so could result in your line being barred"

The final paragraph is therefore -

> Your bill for July was issued on August 2nd for a total amount of $113.
>   You have a grace period until August 23rd to settle your account. Failure to do so could result in your line being barred.

Comment: a phishing email! LOL I just work in a call center in English. I would like to learn more vocab about bills, money, and business. I'd like to sound like a native so that everybody understands me. I don't want them to get me wrong because it's something related to money.

Comment: Well I wanted to be honest :)  It DOES read, in the original form, like a phishing email.

Comment: To me (British English) the phrase "You have a grace period" sounds odd.

Comment: @ʎəʞouɐɪ so what's the correct sentence?